# How to avoid Aurora Postgres running out of memory for large insert into (select ...) query?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, sql-insert, jooq

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to move about 2m records from one table into another. To do this, I'm doing an `insert` statement which is fed by a `select` query.

```
insert into my_table (
   select a, b, c
   from my_other_table 
   where (condition)  
)
```

However, while running this, I keep running out of memory.

**What I expected** (and why I'm confused):

If the working set was larger than could fit in memory, I totally thought Postgres would buffer pages onto the disk and do the write iteratively behind the scenes.

However, what's happening is that it apparently tries to read **all** of the `select`ed content into memory prior to stuffing it into the other table.

Even on our chunky r5.2xl instance, it consumes all of the memory until eventually the OOM Killer fires and the Aurora reboots the instance.

[image]

This graph is showing freeable memory dip down to zero everytime I run the query. The memory shooting back up is due to the instance automatically being killed and rebooted due to OOM.

**My main question:**

1. Why is Postgresql not being smarter and doing its own pagination behind the scenes?
2. Is there some setting I need to enable to get it to be aware of its memory limitations?

**What I've tried:**

Adjusting `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` parameters.

Aurora's default `shared_buffer` value allocates 20gb to our instance. I've tried dialing this down to 10gb, and then  6.5gb (restarting each time) but to no avail. The only affect was to make the query take *ages* and still ultimately consume all memory available after running for about 30min.

I similarly tried setting `work_mem` all the way to allowable minimum, but this seemingly had no effect on the end result as well.

**What I can do as a work around:**

I could, of course, do the pagination / batching from the client:

```
computeBatchOffsets(context).forEach(batchOffset ->
    context.insertInto(BLAH)
      .select(DSL.asterisk())
      .from(FOO)
      .limit(batchOffset)
      .offset(batchOffset)
      .execute()
```

But, in addition to it being slower than just letting the database do it, it "feels" like something the database should *surely* be able to do internally. So, I'm confused why I'd need to handle it at the client level.

Comment: other than your query, what is the load on the database like?  Are there other clients at all?  Are there writes going into the tables in question?  Reads from them?

Comment: Effectively zilch. We're really the only database client. It's not serving general traffic.

Comment: Do you have triggers or foreign key constraints on your `insert into` table?

Comment: @jjanes No triggers or foreign keys. Only a unique constraint on the PK, which is a serial int.

Comment: Sounds like AWS's secret sauce mucked something up.  I've never seen community PostgreSQL do that in the absence of triggers and FK.

Comment: You should post the `explain` for that select and see what happens when it runs